# Klocwork Get the amount of issues in a provided build number

Tags: bash, shell, unix, version-control, klocwork

How can i get the number issues of a specified build number in klocwork insights 10.0, i'll need to use this in a bash script.

Answer (score 4):

Klocwork has a [WebAPI](http://docs.klocwork.com/Insight-10.0/Klocwork_Insight_Web_API_cookbook) which you can use to query this type of information from a bash script, for example with `curl`. API documentation is also provided on your Klocwork server at http://*klocwork_server_host*:*port*/review/api, for example http://localhost:8080/review/api.

The query:

```
curl --data "action=search&user=my_account&project=my_project&query=build:build_1 status:Analyze state:New,Existing&ltoken=xxxx" http://localhost:8080/review/api
```

will return a list of all open (state *New* and *Existing*), non-cited (status *Analyze*) issues found in a build named *build_1* of project *my_project*.

For a list of the keywords you can use in the query string with the search action, see [Searching in Klocwork Review](http://docs.klocwork.com/Insight-10.0/Searching_in_Klocwork_Review#Supported_keywords).

If you want just a summary of the number of defects instead of getting the whole list, you can use the report action:

```
curl --data "action=report&user=my_account&project=my_project&build=build_1&x=Category&y=Component&filterQuery=status:Analyze state:New,Existing&ltoken=xxxx" http://localhost:8080/review/api
```

which returns back a summary of the number of defects by checker category (taxonomy) and component. Sample output is below:

```
{"rows":[{"id":1,"name":"C and C++"},{"id":3,"name":"MISRA C"},{"id":4,"name":"MISRA C++"}],"columns":[{"id":5,"name":"System Model"}],"data":[[122],[354],[890]],"warnings":[]}
```

You can modify the x and y axis parameters to produce different breakdowns of the issues, for example by Severity and State instead:

```
curl --data "action=report&user=my_account&project=my_project&build=build_3&x=Severity&y=State&filterQuery=state:New,Existing,Fixed&ltoken=xxxx" http://localhost:8080/review/api
```

output:

```
{"rows":[{"id":1,"name":"Critical"},{"id":2,"name":"Error"},{"id":3,"name":"Warning"},{"id":4,"name":"Review"}],"columns":[{"id":-1,"name":"Existing"},{"id":-1,"name":"Fixed"},{"id":-1,"name":"New"}],"data":[[10,5,2],[20,6,1],[45,11,3],[1112,78,23]],"warnings":[]}
```

The [WebAPI cookbook documentation](http://docs.klocwork.com/Insight-10.0/Klocwork_Insight_Web_API_cookbook#Example:_Report_detected_issues) has an example of using python with the report action and processing and formatting the response.

**EDITED:**  Fix typos in examples: "&build:build_id" to "&build=build_id"